# Can anyone assist with the translation of this seal mark? (Characters identified: 乾州王氏)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image]This mark is one of several that are located on a Tang dynasty style watercolor painting that I own. However, it is this one that I'm most interested in knowing the meaning of. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

"乾州" means a city nowadays in Hunan province. "王氏" means a man whose name is "王氏" or a man whose first name is "王".

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm going to have to respectfully disagree with you on the characters in the upper and lower right corner which appear to refer to the emperor Qianlong.  More feedback is welcome

Comment: @AOD, it is not 乾隆 (Qianlong). https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYwgw.png ; 乾州 is correct

Comment: Understood and appreciated thank you very much